# python loop result of sum within a range of 0 to 10 so that 2-4=9

Tags: python, range, one-time-pad

So I am working on a script for numerical one time pads
but the issue is that I would like the result of the sums to stay within a specific range
of 0 to 10 so that

```
2-4=9  [9, 10, 0, 1, 2]
4-9=6  [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
7+8=4  [7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here is my script

```
#list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
#sum = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]  1 = addition, 0 = subtraction
#of = [2, 4, 3, 9, 5, 6, 8, 7, 0, 1,]

length = len(list) 
i = 0

while i < length: 
    x = list[i] 
    s = sum[i] 
    y = of[i] 
    
    if s == 1:
      z = x + y
    else:
      z = x - y 

    print(z)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [modular arithmetic](https://mod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
>>> (2-9)%11
4
>>> (4-9)%11
6
>>> (7+8)%11
4
```

Comment: nice work figuring out what the real task was. I was baffled.